# Do Muslim sources address the topic of aliens?

Tags: reference-request, alien

Is the topic of extraterrestrial life discussed in Muslim sources? Could/should theoretical aliens become Muslims? What types of legal issues would arise if aliens made contact with people?

For the purpose of this question, let us assume that we are talking about an intelligent species from another planet or galaxy. I am not talking about Jinn or other spiritual beings.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, no! There's no mention of any such creatures!

Comment: Jinns are aliens.

Comment: @infatuated So do any modern scholars discuss it? Could aliens become Muslims?

Comment: Was your question directed at me or Sayyid? There is no talk of aliens in Islam unless you consider [jinns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jinn) to be aliens.

Comment: @infatuated No modern scholars address the idea? Not a single one?

Comment: @Daniel, not a single one, as far as I know, not so at least in my birthplace. It's probably because they regard the rumors as beneath notice. I've personally not taken the topic seriously either.

Answer (score 2):

Does this verse in the Qur'an, answer your question?

Qur'an - [Surat Al-Ĥaj 22:18](http://quran.com/22/18) :

> "Do you not see that to Allah prostrates whoever is in the heavens and whoever is on the earth and the sun, the moon, the stars, the mountains, the trees, the moving creatures and many of the people? But upon many the punishment has been justified. And he whom Allah humiliates - for him there is no bestower of honor. Indeed, Allah does what He wills."

Comment: very good, and neatly mentioned, it includes evrything even if it doesn't exist the way we know it

Answer (score 0):

jins are essentially aliens because they can see us, we cant see them, they can travel faster then fastest (because a jin transported throne of sulaiman allaihis salam over a great distance in a period that is described in quran as shorter than the speed of blink of eye). jins can go outside earth they are not dependent on oxygen (smokeless flame means literally no combustion = no byproduct). They can materialise into humans and animals.

what more charechteristics of aliens do you want to see(from fiction or something sci-fi). I'm sorry but we already know them and a lot of there charechteristics.

When Quran was revealed 1400 years ago, a verse also related to jins stated them having families, tribes and even horses (perhaps jin horse) as means of transportation, same as we humans had that time (but the horse we can see), if we have evolved this much, planes rockets and such, I see no harm in assuming that they have something similar more or less.

Also from Surah Nas : the last three verses make it clear that jin have the ability to affect our subconcious mind.

These are all the things that I think an advanced life form may have. Afterall iblis also had ego over his being a higher life form than us humans

Answer (score -5):

The Quran clearly states that allah created **3 life forms only**: Jinns, Angels and Humans.

> And I did not create the jinn and mankind except to worship Me. http://quran.com/51/56

**As for angels:**

> And [mention, O Muhammad], when your Lord said to the angels, "Indeed, I will make upon the earth a **successive authorit**y." They said, "Will You place upon it one who causes corruption therein and sheds blood, while we declare Your praise and sanctify You?" Allah said, "Indeed, I know that which you do not know." http://quran.com/2/30

**Note:** According to famous Quran interpreter *Ibn kathir*, the angles asked "*Will You place upon it one who causes corruption therein and sheds blood*" because jinn used to do that before creating Humans.

Now since the Quran didn't mention other life forms then scholars don't have to worry or talk about aliens.

Comment: @DavidWallace, I think you are taking my words literally. Which makes you miss the main point of my answer...

Comment: Jinn, Human, Angles... What about animals?