# Do aliens exist?

Tags: creation

Do aliens or extra terrestrials exist what does the Quran say according to this? I kind of believe there is life the reason why I say kinda is because I don't what Islam thinks of this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [human or creature outside earth?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/27820/human-or-creature-outside-earth) and http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/14436/do-muslim-sources-address-the-topic-of-aliens

Comment: Even if they exist, it would be a sign of qiyama, coming of day of judgement.

Answer (score 0):

> وَلِلَّهِ يَسْجُدُ مَا فِي السَّمَاوَاتِ وَمَا فِي الْأَرْضِ مِنْ
>   دَابَّةٍ وَالْمَلَائِكَةُ وَهُمْ لَا يَسْتَكْبِرُونَ
>
> And to Allah prostrates whatever is in the heavens and whatever is on
>   the earth of creatures, and the angels [as well], and they are not
>   arrogant.  "surah al-nahl ayat 49"

From the Aya we can understand that there are another creatures prostrates to Allah Live in the heavens.