# Does the Qur'an indicate vampires, werewolves, and aliens exist?

Tags: quran, jinn

Do vampires, werewolves, aliens, etc., exist in real life? What does Quran say about these things?

Comment: Why would you think they exist? Is there any outside (scientific) evidence you have to justify it?

Comment: The question part on aliens has been addressed on the site several times. It is recommended to ask separate questions. See for example: [Do Muslim sources address the topic of aliens?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/14436/do-muslim-sources-address-the-topic-of-aliens)

Answer (score 3):

Questions of the form *Is X in the Qur'an?* can be answered by searching for `quran X` in a search engine.  Everything in the Qur'an has been written about extensively online, so there's invariably many obvious hits if something is actually in the Qur'an.

In this case:

- [`quran vampires`](https://cn.bing.com/search?q=quran+vampires) does not return relevant pages, so we conclude that vampires are not in the Qur'an.
- [`quran werewolves`](https://cn.bing.com/search?q=quran+werewolves) does not return relevant pages, so we conclude that werewolves in not the Qur'an.
- [`quran aliens`](https://cn.bing.com/search?q=quran+aliens) returns some low-quality hits.  Webpages like [this one](http://www.endphysics.com/aliens_in_the_quran.html) would love to highlight any clear-cut evidence of aliens in the Qur'an, but since they don't, it's likely the authors failed to find any.

  Instead they quote the verse [Qur'an 65:12](https://quran.com/65/12): *It is Allah who has created seven heavens and of the earth, the like of them.*  Although, it's hard to tell how applicable this is to aliens (if at all)

  In fact, this question was asked here: [Do Muslim sources address the topic of aliens?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/14436/17163)  The top answer quotes [Qur'an 22:18](https://quran.com/22/18): *Do you not see that to Allah prostrates whoever is in the heavens and whoever is on the earth and the sun, the moon, the stars, the mountains, the trees, the moving creatures and many of the people?*  Again, it's hard to tell how applicable this is to aliens (if at all).

Answer (score 1):

There is no reference to vampires or werewolves in the Quran.

With respect to aliens, I assume you mean extra terrestrials and not angels & jinns.

> وَمِنْ آيَاتِهِ خَلْقُ السَّمَاوَاتِ وَالْأَرْضِ وَمَا بَثَّ فِيهِمَا
>   مِنْ دَابَّةٍ ۚ وَهُوَ عَلَىٰ جَمْعِهِمْ إِذَا يَشَاءُ قَدِيرٌ
>
> And of his signs is the creation of the heavens and earth and what **He
>   has dispersed throughout them of creatures.** And He, for gathering them
>   when He wills, is competent.
>
> [Quran (42:29)](https://quran.com/42/29)

And angels are not part of that group of creatures.

> وَلِلَّهِ يَسْجُدُ مَا فِي السَّمَاوَاتِ وَمَا فِي الْأَرْضِ مِنْ
>   دَابَّةٍ وَالْمَلَائِكَةُ وَهُمْ لَا يَسْتَكْبِرُونَ
>
> And to Allah prostrates whatever is in the heavens and whatever is on
>   the earth of creatures, **and the angels [as well]**, and they are not
>   arrogant.
>
> [Quran (16:49)](https://quran.com/16/49)

And

> اللَّهُ الَّذِي خَلَقَ سَبْعَ سَمَاوَاتٍ وَمِنَ الْأَرْضِ مِثْلَهُنَّ
>   يَتَنَزَّلُ الْأَمْرُ بَيْنَهُنَّ لِتَعْلَمُوا أَنَّ اللَّهَ عَلَىٰ
>   كُلِّ شَيْءٍ قَدِيرٌ وَأَنَّ اللَّهَ قَدْ أَحَاطَ بِكُلِّ شَيْءٍ
>   عِلْمًا
>
> **Allah is He Who created seven heavens, and of the earth their like.**
>   Between them the Command keeps coming down, that you may know that
>   Allah is Ever-Determiner over everything and that Allah has already
>   encompassed everything in knowledge.
>
> [Quran (65:12)](https://quran.com/65/12)

Most importantly, we humans are not even aware of the various creations that Allah has preferred over us:

> وَلَقَدْ كَرَّمْنَا بَنِي آدَمَ وَحَمَلْنَاهُمْ فِي الْبَرِّ
>   وَالْبَحْرِ وَرَزَقْنَاهُمْ مِنَ الطَّيِّبَاتِ وَفَضَّلْنَاهُمْ عَلَىٰ
>   كَثِيرٍ مِمَّنْ خَلَقْنَا تَفْضِيلًا
>
> And We have certainly honored the children of Adam and carried them on
>   the land and sea and provided for them of the good things and
>   preferred them **over much of what We have created**, with [definite]
>   preference. [Quran (17:70)](https://quran.com/17/70)

To summarize, we do not know much about vampires or werewolves as there is no mention of them in either the Quran or any Sahih Hadiths. W.r.t extra terrestrials, there is a healthy conversation among the ulema with the majority not denying that may exist. One of the attributes of Allah is Al-Khaliq and He continues to creates if and when He Wills. He Says Be and It Is.

Comment: Vampires don’t exist. They are Transylvanian mythological creatures. I tell you from my own studies and experience.

Answer (score -1):

We where told about jinns who come in the form of dogs, maybe werewolves, and jinns which fly, maybe aliens and a vampire is someone who drinks blood which we know the shaytaan does

Answer (score -1):

**In the name of God, the Beneficent, the Merciful**

**All praise belongs to God. He does what he wishes. No one can object Him. He does not require anybody’s suggestion. He is not bound by anyone. He is not afraid of anyone. Indeed, all praises belongs to God who dominates all and no one can ever dominate Him.**

---

Thank you for your question. I’ll start to answer the first question.

**Q-1:** Does Quran indicates that vampires exist?

**Answer:** Vampires are Transylvanian mythological creatures that suck blood from a living beings. This myth it was inspired by an British man, named **John Polidori**, with his novel **The Vampyre** launched in libraries in 1819. This novel is pure myth. Pure fiction!!! It is like you’re asking wether Santa Claus is real or not.

In Quran it mentions **only** what exist!!!

In case you don’t believe me, please visit the following site:

1. [**Vampire**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vampire)

**Q-2:** Do werewolves exist according to Quran?

**Answer:** The answer is very simple. No. And I’ll tell you why. Because, it is pure fiction. Werewolves are  famous mythological Romanian creatures found in **Middle Ages** in Europe. These mythological creatures appeared in 1 A.D. by John Polidori, the same writer who wrote the novel about vampires, Dracula...

The following informations is taken from:

1. [**Werewolf**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Werewolf)
2. [**Vârcolac**](https://ro.wikipedia.org/wiki/V%C3%A2rcolac)
3. [**The history of werewolves legend**](https://www.historicmysteries.com/history-of-the-werewolf-legend/)

**CONCLUSION:** Werewolves, are pure fictional creatures that are originated from  Romania. They are fictional like **Harry Potter** .

**Q-3:** Do aliens exist according to Quran?

Now we have reached the final question! There are many signs in the world that aliens do exist.

NASA has discovered on planet Mars a figure that looks like an Egyptian Sphinx, and of course is not man made, is alien made. [**EXPRESS**](https://www.express.co.uk/news/weird/966598/Mars-life-alien-statue-sphinx-NASA-photo-UFO-evidence-ancient-aliens)

In 1963 May 15, Gordon Cooper, an American astronaut, has seen a  glowing, greenish object ahead of him quickly approaching his capsule in space that was coming towards him [**UFO Sightings by Astronauts**](https://www.syti.net/UFOSightings.html)

Also, God Said in the Quran:

> ”And to God prostrates whatever creature is in the heavens and whatever is on the Earth, and also the angels, and they are not arrogant.” **[The Holy Quran 16:49]**

The sentence “whatever creature is in the heavens and whatever is on the Earth”, it referred that intelligent aliens do prostrate to God, just like we do.

**FINAL CONCLUSION:** Werewolves and Vampires are 100% pure fictional creatures. And alien civilizations do 100% exist

**Praise be to God the Lord of the worlds the One Who is clear of resembling the creation, all nonbefitting attributes, and all that which the blasphemers unrightfully say about Him**

Comment: Can it be certain that Aliens exist? Wouldn't it be safer to say the Quran does not contradict with the existence of extraterrestrial life?

Comment: @Riz-waan what do you mean?

Comment: He means that the existence of Aliens is not explicitly confirmed by the Qur'an, but it certainly doesn't contradict what the Qur'an says as one could read between the lines a kind of confirmation so saying 100% exist sounds a bit exaggerated as I don't know of any reliable Muslim scholar who confirmed this.

Comment: Yeah, also the Quran says whatever is on the heavens and Earth and technically nothing about other planets which is what aliens are generally associated to